# Joining values with commas using awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to generate a WHERE clause for SQL statement using the Process id from UNIX .

```
spid=$(ps -ef|grep "LOCAL=NO"|awk {'print $2'})
for (( i=0; i<${#spid[@]}; i++ ))  
do 
    if [ ${i} -eq 0 ]; then 
        where="'${spid[$i]}'"; 
    else 
        where=${where}", '${spid[$i]}'";
    fi 
done

echo $where
```

Expected OUTPUT

```
'45674','4757','34535'
```

Current Output

```
'45674,4757,34535'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a set of parentheses, so the assignment to `spid` is creating a single string, not an array.  Use:

```
spid=( $(ps -ef|grep "LOCAL=NO"|awk {'print $2'}) )
for (( i=0; i<${#spid[@]}; i++ ))  
do 
    if [ ${i} -eq 0 ]; then 
        where="'${spid[$i]}'"; 
    else 
        where=${where}", '${spid[$i]}'";
    fi 
done

echo $where
```

The `=( ... )` notation, where the spaces are not technically necessary, defines an array assignment.

The only thing I'm not clear on is where the embedded commas are coming from. Your expected output should include some spaces since your concatenation operation includes a space.

Were it my code, I'd fix up quite a lot of minor spacing and quoting issues:

```
spid=( $(ps -ef | awk '/LOCAL=NO/ {print $2}') )
for (( i = 0; i < ${#spid[@]}; i++ ))  
do 
    if [ ${i} -eq 0 ]; then 
        where="'${spid[$i]}'"
    else
        where="$where, '${spid[$i]}'"
    fi
done

echo "$where"
```

Or, even more likely, I'd lose the `if` too:

```
spid=( $(ps -ef | awk '/LOCAL=NO/ {print $2}') )
pad=""
for (( i = 0; i < ${#spid[@]}; i++ ))  
do 
    where="$where$pad'${spid[$i]}'"
    pad=", "
done
echo "$where"
```

Or have `awk` generate all the output:

```
ps -ef |
awk '/LOCAL=NO/ { printf("%s'\''%s'\''", pad, $2; pad=", "} END { printf "\n" }'
```

The only puzzle-piece in there is the `'\''` sequence that appears twice; it is the canonical way to embed a single quote in a single quoted string.  The first single quote terminates the current segment of the single-quoted string; the backslash single quote embeds a single quote, and the other single quote starts the next segment of the single quoted string.  Again, there are other ways to do that, but using double quotes is harder than using single quotes.

Comment: +1 It's also worth pointing out that there are some quoting issues. For example, this would be better: `spid=( $(ps -ef | awk '/LOCAL=NO/ { print $2 }') )`